# Have multiple inputs going into multiple graphs but only 3 out of the 5 are working

Tags: shiny, plotly

I have created multiple selectInputs that will alter multiple graphs when something from the drop down menu has been selected. Currently only 3 out of the 5 graphs are working even though they all have the same code. So far the trafficking type, sub type and gender work but the control method and transportation method are not.

UI:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Human Trafficking"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      selectInput("Source", "Choose a Data Source: ", choices = sort(unique(newNgo$Data.Source)), selected = NULL,
                  multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),
      selectInput("Nationality", "Select a nation: ", choices = " "),
      dateInput("startdate", "Start Date:", value = "2019-08-01", format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                min = "2000-01-01", max = "2019-09-04"),

      dateInput("enddate", "End Date:", value = "2019-09-05", format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                min = "2000-01-02", max = "2019-09-05")
      #actionButton("button1", "Apply"),
      #actionButton("reset_input", "Reset inputs")
    )
  ),
fluidRow(     
      box(width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
          title = "Trafficking Type", 
          selectInput("traffickingType", "Choose a trafficking type: ", 
                      choices = sort(unique(newNgo$Trafficking.Type)), selected = NULL,
                      multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),
          #actionButton("button2", "Apply"),
          plotlyOutput("coolplot", width = '750px', height = '300px')
      ),

      box(width = 6, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
          title = "Trafficking Sub-Type", 
          selectInput("traffickingSubType", "Choose a trafficking sub type: ",
                      choices = sort(unique(newNgo$Trafficking.Sub.Type)), selected = NULL,
                      multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),
          #actionButton("button3", "Apply"),
          plotlyOutput("Sub", width = '750px', height = '300px')
      )
    ),

    fluidRow(
      box(width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
          title = "Victim Gender", 
          selectInput("victimGender", "Choose a gender: ", 
                      choices = sort(unique(newNgo$Victim.Gender)), selected = NULL,
                      multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),
          #actionButton("button4", "Apply"),
          plotlyOutput("gender", width = '250px', height = '200px')
      ),

      box(width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
          title = "Transport Method",
          selectInput("transp", "Choose a transportation method: ", 
                      choices = sort(unique(newNgo$Transportation.Method)), selected = NULL,
                      multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),
          #actionButton("button4", "Apply"),
          plotlyOutput("transportMethod", width = '250px', height = '200px')
      ),

      box(width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
          title = "Control Method",
          selectInput("control", "Choose a control method: ", 
                      choices = sort(unique(newNgo$Control.Method)), selected = NULL,
                      multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),
          #actionButton("button4", "Apply"),
          plotlyOutput("controlMethod", width = '250px', height = '200px')
    )
```

Server:

```
output$coolplot <- renderPlotly({
     req(input$Nationality)

     if(!is.null(input$Nationality)) {
       newNgo <- newNgo %>% filter(Victim.Nationality %in% input$Nationality)
     }
     if(!is.null(input$gender)) {
       newNgo <- newNgo %>% filter(Victim.Gender %in% input$gender)
     }
     if(!is.null(input$traffickingType)) {
       newNgo <- newNgo %>% filter(Trafficking.Type %in% input$traffickingType)
     }
     if(!is.null(input$traffickingSubType)) {
       newNgo <- newNgo %>% filter(Trafficking.Sub.Type %in% input$traffickingSubType)
     }
     if(!is.null(input$Source)) {
       newNgo <- newNgo %>% filter(Data.Source %in% input$Source)
     }

     plot_ly(newNgo, labels = ~Trafficking.Type, type = "pie") %>%
       layout(showlegend = FALSE)
  })
output$control <- renderPlotly({
     req(input$Nationality)

     if(!is.null(input$Nationality)) {
       newNgo <- newNgo %>% filter(Victim.Nationality %in% input$Nationality)
     }
     if(!is.null(input$gender)) {
       newNgo <- newNgo %>% filter(Victim.Gender %in% input$gender)
     }
     if(!is.null(input$traffickingType)) {
       newNgo <- newNgo %>% filter(Trafficking.Type %in% input$traffickingType)
     }
     if(!is.null(input$traffickingSubType)) {
       newNgo <- newNgo %>% filter(Trafficking.Sub.Type %in% input$traffickingSubType)
     }
     if(!is.null(input$Source)) {
       newNgo <- newNgo %>% filter(Data.Source %in% input$Source)
     }

     plot_ly(newNgo, labels = ~Control.Method, type = "pie") %>%
       layout(showlegend = FALSE)
   })
```

I have attached the code from the server with one graph that works and one that doesn't work. I also attached all the different inputs I have from the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `plotlyOutput` in the ui has the id `controlMethod`, whereas your `output` id in the server is `control`. Change the latter to `output$controlMethod`.